# Enable soap 7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to enable soap, but there's no way.

The thing is that I have PHP 7.4, which does not have php7.4-soap because it is not available for 16.04, but I also have php7.0 with php7.0-soap.

When I try to activate php soap in /etc/php/7.0/apache2 (removing the `;` in php.ini) nothing happens, not is it in the `phpinfo()` file.

I have been looking for information about this and I have not been able to find much, although I have tried all the possible solutions I have not yet found the key.

What might be happening here?

You can check php.ini on mundodelmueble.es/test.php

Comment: Ubuntu 1604 is out of support. Upgrade (free of charge) to a supported version to get more recent versions of popular software packages (and to continue to get security updates, to ensure your system is less vulnerable to attackers).

Comment: Will upgrading ubuntu 16.04 to the latest version cause me to lose my web configurations?

Comment: You mean your Apache config? If you do an in-place upgrade then, no not as far as I know. But as with any upgrade, it would be wise to take a backup of anything on the machine you care about before proceeding. A bit of careful planning and reading of release notes of the application versions you'll be upgrading to as well would be sensible.

Comment: I am not a fan of Ubuntu upgrades, I don't think they are reliable (and they are certainly not reversible). I think it is better to start up a new server, and move your services from one to the other (e.g. using DNS changes).